# Python get value from input element with lxml xpath

Tags: python, xpath, paypal

i want to make paypal cURL login, so i need auth value.  i try to get auth value from html source with this python code

```
import requests
import lxml.html
import StringIO
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
r = requests.get("https://paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-run")
login_page = r.text.encode('utf-8') #printing html source
html = lxml.html.fromstring(login_page) #printing <Element html at 0x7f19cb242e$
auth = html.xpath('//input[@name="auth"]') #printing [<InputElement 7fb0971e9f1$
print auth
```

but the above code printing this `[<InputElement 7fb0971e9f18 name='auth' type='hidden'>]` , so how i can get auth value with decoded `&#x2d; &#x2d;  &#x2e;` ? the input section looks like this

```
<input name="auth" type="hidden" value="ADPifNsidn&#x2d;P0G6WmiMMeJbjEhnhIvZCNg7Fk11NUxc0DyYWzrH&#x2d;xk5ydV&#x2e;85WCzy">
```

thanks you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you'd like to retrieve the `auth` attribute of that element, use

```
auth = html.xpath('//input[@name="auth"]/@value')
```

there is no need to decode anything, entities are expanded automatically when lxml parses HTML, and therefore the output will be

```
$ python sample.py 
['AmmyYuqCDmZRcSs6MaQi2tKhzZiyAX0eSERKqTi3pLB5pdceB726lx7jhXU2MGDN6']
```